# Math.random if statement error

Tags: java

```
    int Comproll1= (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
    int Comproll2= (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
      while (m==1)
    { 
        {
        if (Comproll1==1 || Comproll2==1)
        {
            System.out.println("One of the computer's dice rolls was a 1, it lost all the points for the round & it is now your turn!");
            cr= cr-cr;
            m++;
        }
        else if (Comproll1==1 && Comproll2==1)
        {
            System.out.println("The Computer rolled 2 1's, their total number of points is now 0 & it is now your turn!");
            cp=cp-cp;
            m++;
        }
        else 
        {
            cr= Comproll1+Comproll2;
            cp= cp+cr;
        }
    }
```

Hey everyone! Above is my code- for some reason regardless, it WILL ALWAYS, no matter what, always display the first option, which is "One of the computer's dice rolls was a 1, it lost all points for the round...". Even when I change the order of the statements, it still does this. Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?? Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, that `int Comproll1 = (int) (Math.random()*6+1)` should be 5+1. What if random returns 6 ? Then you will have a 7 on the dice.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev `Math.random()` returns a float `< 1` so the return value of `Math.random() * 6 + 1` can never be higher then `6.99...` and therefore 6 if casted to integer.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev That's not true. The result of `Math.random()` is guaranteed to be < 1, therefore, `Math.random() * 6` will always be < 6 and `Math.random() * 6 + 1` will always be < 7. The cast to `int` makes 6 the maximum value.

Comment: Thanks. My bad. I checked the docs. rand < 1 and the int casting will take of the rest. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, because you aren't re-rolling

```
int Comproll1= (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
int Comproll2= (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
while (m==1)
{
```

Should be

```
while (m==1)
{
  int Comproll1= (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
  int Comproll2= (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
```

Also, Java naming convention is camel case for variables (and starts with a lower case letter). So, `Comproll1` might be `compRoll1`. Finally, I personally prefer [`Random.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) and for 6 sided dice that might look like

```
Random rand = new Random();
while (m==1)
{
  int compRoll1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
  int compRoll2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
```

**Edit** Actually, you also need to reverse the order of your tests. Because if either is true then it will never be possible that the test for both being true will be entered.

```
if (Comproll1==1 || Comproll2==1) {
  // Here.
}else if (Comproll1==1 && Comproll2==1) {
  // Will never enter here.
}
```

Switch the order to,

```
if (Comproll1==1 && Comproll2==1) {
  // Both.
}else if (Comproll1==1 || Comproll2==1) {
  // Either.
}
```

Comment: Isn't it because he's actually ORing the two conditions in the first if statement? Looking at the second if condition, he's ANDing, so assuming that's true, the first if statement should be true as well. EDIT: it's probably both reasons though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to check if they are both 1, before checking if either of them are 1s. If we look at the code:

```
if (Comproll1==1 || Comproll2==1)
{
    System.out.println("One of the computer's dice rolls was a 1, it lost all the points for the round & it is now your turn!");
    cr= cr-cr;
    m++;
}
else if (Comproll1==1 && Comproll2==1)
{
    System.out.println("The Computer rolled 2 1's, their total number of points is now 0 & it is now your turn!");
    cp=cp-cp;
    m++;
}
```

if:

`Comproll1` = 1

`Comproll2` = 1

You expect that it will go into the `else if (Comproll1==1 && Comproll2==1)` however, if this is true than `if (Comproll1==1 || Comproll2==1)` will **always** be true.

To fix this simply change the order of the `if`s, like this:

```
if (Comproll1==1 && Comproll2==1)
{
    System.out.println("The Computer rolled 2 1's, their total number of points is now 0 & it is now your turn!");
    cp=cp-cp;
    m++;
}
else if (Comproll1==1 || Comproll2==1)
{
    System.out.println("One of the computer's dice rolls was a 1, it lost all the points for the round & it is now your turn!");
    cr= cr-cr;
    m++;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

(Also you need to reroll the dice (as Elliott Frisch Said in his answer))

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of your if statements. Logically, if one of the two comparisons are true, the first statement will execute. In the case that the second conditions `else if (Comproll1==1 && Comproll2==1)` are true, the first conditions `if (Comproll1==1 || Comproll2==1)` will also be true.

Since you've chained the if statements in an if-else-if fashion, the first if statement to equate to true will execute.

```
    if (Comproll1==1 && Comproll2==1)
    {
        System.out.println("The Computer rolled 2 1's, their total number of points is now 0 & it is now your turn!");
        cp=cp-cp;
        m++;
    }
    else if (Comproll1==1 || Comproll2==1)
    {
        System.out.println("One of the computer's dice rolls was a 1, it lost all the points for the round & it is now your turn!");
        cr= cr-cr;
        m++;
    }
    else 
    {
        cr= Comproll1+Comproll2;
        cp= cp+cr;
    }
```